# Import / Export MS Project in Outsystems

Tags: rest, ms-project, outsystems

How to Import / Export MS Project file types in Outsytems applications?

Client doesn't want to get an excel to import in MS project.
I have searched the forge and haven't found anything related.
I haven't found a direct integration REST to use in Outsytems.
Is my only option create an extension and use integration studio?